# Rewriting a weird URL string with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like rewrite a URL string from `?s=` to `/search/` with `.htaccess`.

Example: `http://hello.com/?s=hey` => `http://hello.com/search/hey`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys, this works for me, taken from [here](http://wpengineer.com/2258/change-the-search-url-of-wordpress/).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)  index.php?s=$1     [QSA,L]
```

This way you will be accessing your site like

`http://hello.com/search/hey` will be interpreted as `http://hello.com/index.php?s=hey`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from index.php?s=key to search/key
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?s=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [L,R,NC]

# external redirect from search/key to index.php?s=key
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```